# Why do reference member variables overwrite eachother?

Tags: c++, reference

in the folowing code, the _bla member of both instances of Var seems to represent the same memory location, as setting the value on one instance also changes the other. When executing the program, the output is:

```
v: 44 v2: 44 x: 22
```

Can someone please explain?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T> class Var {
  T  &_bla;
public:
  Var(T t) : _bla(t) {}

  int bla() const {
    return _bla;
  }
};

using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;

  int x = 22;
  Var<int> v = {x};
  Var<int> v2 = {44};

  cout << "v: " << v.bla() << " v2: " << v2.bla() << " x: " << x << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce!](http://ideone.com/NWM9eT)

Answer (score 7):

It's *undefined behaviour*, which means everything is possible.

The parameter `t` of ctor is passed by value, it will be copied from the argument and then assigned to `_bla` by reference, and when get out of the scope of ctor, the parameter `t` is deallocated, now the member variable `_bla` become dangled reference.

You may reconsider your design, do you need the member variable to be a reference? And what should be the type of parameter `t`? By const reference, by reference, by value? (In your case, it's obviously wrong to pass it by value.) It's better to consider carefully when you use reference for member variables.

Answer (score 2):

The way I see it, they actually reference the parameter of Var`s constructor, wich is a temporary copy that happens to be in the same memory location and might be even overwritten later in the program.

If your membervariablesare supposed to reference a non member variable,you have to pass it by reference. However,in most cases this is a really bad and dangerous design.

Answer (score 0):

The following code would make more sense:

```
template<typename T> class Var {
    T  _bla;
public:
    Var(const T & t) : _bla(t) {}

    int bla() const {
        return _bla;
    }
};
```

Essentially the class would keep a copy by value.

In your original code, you were taking a reference to a temporary object who was destroyed before you actually print its value. Thus it was undefined behavior.